# Finding the isomorphism type of an elliptic curve

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, elliptic-curves

Consider the elliptic curve $E: y^2=x^3+1$ over $\mathbb{F_q}$ where $q = 15485863$ (the $1000000^{\text{th}}$ prime).

I have computed (using sage) that $P=(15065540,4435916)$ has order $5160153 = 3\cdot19\cdot90529$
and that $|E(\mathbb{F}_q)| = 15480459 = 3^2\cdot19\cdot90529$

I am asked to find the isomorphism type of $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$, I know from the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups that $E(\mathbb{F}_q) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3^2\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/90529\mathbb{Z}$

or that $E(\mathbb{F}_q) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/90529\mathbb{Z}$

I would like to know if there's any way that I can discard one of this options. I guess that I would have to find a point of order 9 or at least two points of order 3, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: sage will tell you the 3 torsion! you could use P.division_points(3) where P is the origin.

Comment: And you can look at the polynomials such that $[3](x,y) = (\frac{u(x,y)}{v(x,y)}, \frac{w(x,y)}{z(x,y)})$ then $[3](x,y) = O$ corresponds to the roots of $V(x) = v(x,\sqrt{x^3+1})v(x,-\sqrt{x^3+1}) \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$.

Comment: @hunter So the 3-torsion points according to what you said and sage are [(0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 1 : 1), (0 : 102 : 1)], this means that there are two points of order 3 and therefore ()≅ℤ/3ℤ×ℤ/3ℤ×ℤ/19ℤ×ℤ/90529ℤ, right?

Comment: If there's only two points of order 3, then the 3-torsion subgroup must be $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$, not two copies of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: `EllipticCurve( GF(nth_prime(1000000)), [0,1] ).order().factor()` delivers in sage `2^2 * 3 * 37 * 43 * 811`. On the other way, there is a big prime `21843131744681521` obtained by factorizing $y_0^2-x_0^3-1$, where $x_0,y_0$ are the coordinates of $P$.